# Encontrar posição em uma matriz através da posição no array?

Tags: algoritmo

Se eu tenho um array, ex:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

e eu transformo este array em uma matriz, ex:

```
           y[0]  y[1]  y[2]

   x[0] =   1  |  2  |  3
           ---------------
   x[1] =   4  |  5  |  6
           ---------------
   x[2] =   7  |  8  |  9
```

E eu tenho a posição do `array` inicial, por exemplo a posição 5 que no caso é o valor -> 6, como faço pra encontrar a posição `x, y` da matriz equivalente a posição do array, no caso deste exemplo seria: `x:1, y:2`.

Comment: variavel_array[5] -> 6
variavel_matriz[1,2] -> 6

Comment: linha = posição_no_array / largura; coluna = posição_no_array % largura (ajuste o offset para seu sistema de coordenadas, veja como obter o truncamento da divisão na linguagem escolhida - % é o operador de resto de divisão)

Comment: @DuilioBenjoino, não entendi seu comentário, apenas replicou o que está na pergunta?

Comment: @Bacco interessante, vou tentar entender matematicamente como encontra isso e aplicar no meu código, valeu. Se quiser transformar em uma respostar, coloco como aceita...

Comment: @matheussoareslacerda Não tinha entendido sua dúvida. Reli e compreendi, creio que a reposta de Anderson Carlos Woss atende ao desejado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo,

Para obter a posição basta você dividir pegar o valor subtrair por 1 e dividir pela quantidade de linhas ou colunas (se for uma matriz perfeita) a posição x será o valor inteiro da divisão e o resto será o y Exemplo:

(5-1)/3 = 1 e o resto é 2 neste caso o array será array [x,y] [1,1]

(6-1)/3 = 1 e o resto é 2 neste caso o array será array [x,y] [1,2]